# Horizontally align elements with different height

Tags: css, alignment

I'm building a web page where the search results should appear horizontally aligned. The elements could have different heights.

The examples I'd like to reproduce are:

- Google Plus posts layout
- Isotope (http://isotope.metafizzy.co).

I tried to use floating elements but you can see my failure in this Plunkr
http://plnkr.co/8ex35N8OraWZBnbE5EoY

Comment: And your question being? How to do this in css? Can you post your current code please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Option #1 : nth-child

If you have a fixed number of columns, you can use :

```css
/* Style */
.item { background: yellow; width: 48px; border: 1px solid black; }
.item:nth-child(2n) { background: blue; }
.item:nth-child(3n) { background: red; }

/* Position */
.container {
    width: 200px;
}
.item {
    float: left;
}
.item:nth-child(4n+1) {
    clear: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="item">foo<br>bar<br>baz<br>qux<br>quux<br>corge<br>grault<br>garply<br>waldo<br>fred<br>plugh<br>xyzzy<br>thud</div>
    <div class="item">foo<br>bar<br>baz<br>qux</div>
    <div class="item">foo<br>bar<br>baz<br>qux<br>quux<br>corge<br>grault<br>garply<br>waldo<br>fred<br>plugh<br>xyzzy<br>thud</div>
    <div class="item">foo<br>bar<br>baz<br>qux<br>quux<br>corge<br>grault<br>garply<br>waldo</div>
    <div class="item">foo<br>bar<br>baz</div>
    <div class="item">foo<br>bar<br>baz<br>qux<br>quux<br>corge<br>grault</div>
    <div class="item">foo</div>
    <div class="item">foo<br>bar<br>baz</div>
</div>
```

### Option #2 : clearfix

Under IE9, you can use a clearfix :

```css
/* Style */
.item { background: yellow; width: 48px; border: 1px solid black; }
.item:nth-child(2n) { background: blue; }
.item:nth-child(3n) { background: red; }

/* Position */
.container {
    width: 200px;
}
.item {
    float: left;
}
.clear {    
    clear: both;
    height: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="item">foo<br>bar<br>baz<br>qux<br>quux<br>corge<br>grault<br>garply<br>waldo<br>fred<br>plugh<br>xyzzy<br>thud</div>
    <div class="item">foo<br>bar<br>baz<br>qux</div>
    <div class="item">foo<br>bar<br>baz<br>qux<br>quux<br>corge<br>grault<br>garply<br>waldo<br>fred<br>plugh<br>xyzzy<br>thud</div>
    <div class="item">foo<br>bar<br>baz<br>qux<br>quux<br>corge<br>grault<br>garply<br>waldo</div>
    <p class="clear">&nbsp;</p>
    <div class="item">foo<br>bar<br>baz</div>
    <div class="item">foo<br>bar<br>baz<br>qux<br>quux<br>corge<br>grault</div>
    <div class="item">foo</div>
    <div class="item">foo<br>bar<br>baz</div>
</div>
```

### Options #3 : rows

Another way to do it under IE9 : add rows.

```css
/* Style */
.item { background: yellow; width: 48px; border: 1px solid black; }
.item:nth-child(2n) { background: blue; }
.item:nth-child(3n) { background: red; }

/* Position */
.container {
    width: 200px;
}
.item {
    float: left;
}
.row {    
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item">foo<br>bar<br>baz<br>qux<br>quux<br>corge<br>grault<br>garply<br>waldo<br>fred<br>plugh<br>xyzzy<br>thud</div>
    <div class="item">foo<br>bar<br>baz<br>qux</div>
    <div class="item">foo<br>bar<br>baz<br>qux<br>quux<br>corge<br>grault<br>garply<br>waldo<br>fred<br>plugh<br>xyzzy<br>thud</div>
    <div class="item">foo<br>bar<br>baz<br>qux<br>quux<br>corge<br>grault<br>garply<br>waldo</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item">foo<br>bar<br>baz</div>
    <div class="item">foo<br>bar<br>baz<br>qux<br>quux<br>corge<br>grault</div>
    <div class="item">foo</div>
    <div class="item">foo<br>bar<br>baz</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Option #4 : columns

This option requires to rearrange items order.

```css
/* Style */
.item { background: yellow; width: 48px; border: 1px solid black; }
.item:nth-child(2n) { background: blue; }
.item:nth-child(3n) { background: red; }

/* Position */
.container {
    width: 200px;
}
.column {
    width: 50px;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="column">
        <div class="item">foo<br>bar<br>baz<br>qux<br>quux<br>corge</div>
        <div class="item">foo<br>bar</div>
        <div class="item">foo<br>bar<br>baz<br>qux<br>quux<br>corge<br>grault<br>garply</div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="item">foo<br>bar<br>baz<br>qux<br>quux<br>corge<br>grault<br>garply<br>waldo<br>fred<br>plugh<br>xyzzy<br>thud</div>
        <div class="item">foo<br>bar</div>
        <div class="item">foo<br>bar<br>baz<br>qux<br>quux<br>corge</div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="item">foo<br>bar<br>baz<br>qux<br>quux</div>
        <div class="item">foo<br>bar<br>baz<br>qux<br>quux<br>corge<br>grault<br>garply<br>waldo<br>fred</div>
        <div class="item">foo<br>bar<br>baz<br>qux</div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="item">foo<br>bar<br>baz</div>
        <div class="item">foo<br>bar<br>baz</div>
        <div class="item">foo<br>bar<br>baz<br>qux<br>quux<br>corge</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### Option #5 : Masonry

Finally, a JS solution with [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) :

```js
var container = document.querySelector('.container');
var msnry = new Masonry( container, {
  // options
  columnWidth: 50,
  itemSelector: '.item'
});
```

```css
/* Style */
.item { background: yellow; width: 48px; border: 1px solid black; }
.item:nth-child(2n) { background: blue; }
.item:nth-child(3n) { background: red; }

/* Position */
.container {
    width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/masonry/3.1.2/masonry.pkgd.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="item">foo<br>bar<br>baz<br>qux<br>quux<br>corge</div>
    <div class="item">foo<br>bar</div>
    <div class="item">foo<br>bar<br>baz<br>qux<br>quux<br>corge<br>grault<br>garply</div>
    <div class="item">foo<br>bar<br>baz<br>qux<br>quux<br>corge<br>grault<br>garply<br>waldo<br>fred<br>plugh<br>xyzzy<br>thud</div>
    <div class="item">foo<br>bar</div>
    <div class="item">foo<br>bar<br>baz<br>qux<br>quux<br>corge</div>
    <div class="item">foo<br>bar<br>baz<br>qux<br>quux</div>
    <div class="item">foo<br>bar<br>baz<br>qux<br>quux<br>corge<br>grault<br>garply<br>waldo<br>fred</div>
    <div class="item">foo<br>bar<br>baz<br>qux</div>
    <div class="item">foo<br>bar<br>baz</div>
    <div class="item">foo<br>bar<br>baz</div>
    <div class="item">foo<br>bar<br>baz<br>qux<br>quux<br>corge</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I'd like to reproduce exactly the same elements disposition as in the examples. I mean that that there should be no vertical space between elements of different rows, independently on their height.

Comment: Ok, so you can have a look on 4th option I just added.

Comment: Thanks! now it looks exactly as I need. Is it possible to get a similar result without dividing the elements in columns? Due to the architecture of my app, it would be painful to divide my result list that way. Let's see the numbering on my Plunkr example.

Comment: This won't be possible in full CSS. But you still can use [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/). Here we go for the 5th option ;) See my edit for a fiddle.